# How can apache access files under /root directory

Tags: apache, xampp

When I access file under /root from apache it returns "Access forbidden!", How can I configure apache to access files under /root?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnYrX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use the next plugin in Apache for specify a user in specific.

Note: This must be specified in the virtualhost.

```sh
apt install libapache2-mpm-itk
a2enmod mpm_itk
```

Example:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  {domain}

    <Directory /root>
        <ifmodule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserID    {user} {group}
        </ifmodule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```